# Javascript JSColor not working on popup page

Tags: jscolor

I used color picker to change color but it didn't work on popup window.
I have some html code which is dynamically added and i want to apply color to text. How i can apply color by using popup page?

Answer (score 2):

The default zIndex of the JSColor popup is probably too small. Because of that the popup is not shown. Go into your jscolor.js file and change the zIndex to 9999

```html
this.zIndex = 9999;
```

Answer (score 2):

@Captuszz is correct that this is probably an issue with the popup's z-index being greater than jscolor's default z-index (1000).

Changing that default would be one possibility. An alternative would be to set the z-index for that particular jscolor instance via configuration:

```
<input class="jscolor {zIndex:9999}" value="ab2567">
```

The "right" z-index value just needs to be greater than the popup's, so I'd suggest looking at the popup's value and then adding 1. Jumping straight to the maximum possible value could end up being a problem later if something else needs to be even more foregrounded.

Also be aware that the jscolor popup isn't rendered within the popup div, so click events within the color picker count as "outside" the popup.